# Food safety of spontaneusly fermented mango

Tags: food-safety, fruit

I had a very big mango on kitchen table for few days and at the stem it got a bit brown, a bit less than half was completely normal, but the inbetween was very soft and had strong alcohol taste and smell. That made me wonder, is it safe to eat fruit that ferments like that?

All the resources I found about it are about trying to ferment it on purpose and how it's safe, but none about this random fermentation.